# Notification not working on API 23

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

my notification is not working on API 23.

My Notfication works succesfull from API 16 to 22

The 100 for calstd/calmin is a default number.

```
 if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        if(calstd==100||calmin==100){
            cancelAlarm();
        }
        else {
            onTimeSet(calstd, calmin);
        }

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, mainsite.class), 0);
        nm1 = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notif = new Notification.Builder(context);
        uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        notif.setContentTitle("Remind Me");
        notif.setContentText("Vergiss deine Pille nicht :)");
        notif.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        notif.setSound(uri);
        notif.setAutoCancel(true);
        notif.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        nm1.notify(15, notif.build());

...
}

 public void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

    intent = new Intent(contexta, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contexta, RQS_1, intent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) contexta.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".Alarm"/>

  <receiver android:name="com.victoriaremindme.AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Its not working after closing the Apps. I cant find the Problem.

Comment: where is the correlation between a alarmManager call and a BootBroadcastReceiver? your question is unclear.

Comment: Is the correlation between a alarmManager call and a BootBroadcastReceiver important for this Problem? I was hoping in API23 is something changed, what i cant find...

Comment: In the others APIs is my App working fine.

Comment: of course! you posted code which does not picture the situation. if you can't describe how they are connected, this can't be answered.

Comment: The Boot Receiver is for the notfication after a restart. The Notifacation was without this not working after a restart.

Comment: Notifications don't get carried over at reboot. I guess this is a valid solution, but unrelated to the question. Please post only the relevant code on your questions. BTW: @Shadab Ansari's answer looks like what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `API 23` and above you can use  `setAndAllowWhileIdle()`

So change your code to

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
            alarmManager. setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

   else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

   else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

Check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) I will try with exact: `alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);`

Comment: setExactAndAllowWhileIdle: can we use this method for repeat alarm for specific time duration (like 1 minutes)?

Answer (score 1):

The difference with 23 is runtime permissions. You need to review your app for **dangerous permissions**. As the new api means the app will not run many task if runtime permissions are not managed, but will either silently ignore the code that requires the permission, or crash.

[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

[Normal and Dangerous Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous)

> - Normal permissions cover areas where your app needs to access data or resources outside the app's sandbox, but where there's very little risk to the user's privacy or the operation of other apps. For example, permission to set the time zone is a normal permission. If an app declares that it needs a normal permission, the system automatically grants the permission to the app. For a full listing of the current normal permissions, see Normal permissions.
> - Dangerous permissions cover areas where the app wants data or resources that involve the user's private information, or could potentially affect the user's stored data or the operation of other apps. For example, the ability to read the user's contacts is a dangerous permission. If an app declares that it needs a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly grant the permission to the app.
>
> **Table 1. Dangerous permissions and permission groups.**

[image]